# "clientless" rdp session to windows 7 professional

Tags: windows-7, rdp, configuration-management, automated-install

I am currently automating the installation of a legacy windows 7 application, that requires a desktop session on the target machine. We are currently setting up automated testing system (using Jenkins) that requires that the desktop app be started and running in a gui session.

This is currently done with a manual step to login to a console with "remote desktop to port 3389" and start this desktop app, however as soon as I try to script this configuration, I run into the problem of needing a GUI app for my rdp tool on the client side.

The application is effectively running as a server, but has a gui that needs to be available within a console or rdesktop session.

Is there a configuration for one of the RDP client tools (for linux or windows) that can connect to the running Rdp server, login and start a session (with no x-server, or local gui app)

***Possible solutions***

1. [Guacamole](http://guac-dev.org/) is a "clientless" rdp gateway, so I think it might be possible to script it to make an initial connection automatically, which is sufficient for my purposes (though it seems pretty heavyweight)
2. python rdp library;    https://github.com/citronneur/rdpy
3. Use the Rdesktop in "bitmap" mode, so it streams the remote session to "disk", rather than to a x-server.

Comment: Would something like this work [PS Open RDP](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Connect-Mstsc-Open-RDP-2064b10b)?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a possible scenario to use something like Powershell remoting to execute a background process and launch your GUI app.

If you need an actual login session it is probably best to simply enable AutoLogin via the registry.